# How to point my domain to ip address using NGINX?

Tags: nginx, dns, vps

I have a problem. I think I went through every single link on the web to find a solution. So i'm trying to figure out why NGINX can't display the desired HTML page. Let me go through what I've done from the very beginning.

I bought a domain. Let's call it example.com. After that I bought VPS. To connect them, I used A records in DNS management:

```
Name      IP Address      TTL 
@         VPS IP Address  28800

Name      IP Address      TTL 
www       VPS IP Address  28800
```

To check if my VPS connected to domain, I used nslookup command in Windows:

```
nslookup sklyar.app 8.8.8.8

╤хЁтхЁ:  dns.google
Address:  8.8.8.8

Non-authoritative answer:
╚ь :     sklyar.app
Address:  VPS IP Address
```

Also I checked the nameservers:

```
nslookup -q=ns sklyar.app 8.8.8.8

╤хЁтхЁ:  dns.google
Address:  8.8.8.8

Non-authoritative answer:
example.com      nameserver = dns4.domainregistrar.com
example.com      nameserver = dns1.domainregistrar.com
example.com      nameserver = dns3.domainregistrar.com
example.com      nameserver = dns2.domainregistrar.com
```

This means that everything is alright, isn't it?
After that I connected to VPS via ssh. Then wrote the series of commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install nginx
sudo ufw allow 'Nginx Full'
```

Then I went to http://VPS IP Address and I saw NGINX starting page.
After that created a simple HTML:

```
sudo mkdir -p /var/www/example.com/html
sudo vim /var/www/example.com/html/index.html
```

In index.html I put:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Welcome to example.com!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Success! The example.com server block is working!</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Then I created NGINX file:

```
sudo vim /etc/nginx/sites-available/example.com
```

Where I put:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /var/www/example.com/html;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

After that I used:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/example.com /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

And when I go to http://example.com it gives me ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED error.

I also tried changing the user in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf, setting this parameter: `server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;`, deploying a Flask app, using tutorial that worked for me on other registrars and VPS before.

What am I doing wrong? Help me please!

Comment: Your question is offtopic here but as your registrar should have explained to you when you bought the domain, since `app` is a Google TLD added to the HSTS preloading list, browsers will only do HTTPS queries to such names, not HTTP ones.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek so I should just use SSL certificate to access the website to solve the problem?

Comment: @PatrickMevzek thank you so much! I was trying to solve this problem for ages, and now I solved it within 10 minutes! Thx a lot!